# json response in ajax undefined

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

so here is my problem, I am returning a list of my model List from a controller through ajax. In response I am getting List but when i try to fill my datatable with this response it shows undefined everywhere
My View:

```
function GetData() {
                pid = $(this).data('id');
                var singleValues = $("#network").val();
                var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                var network = { "network": id };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/GetData',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(network),
                    success: function (response) {
                    //    console.log(response);
                        alert(response);
                            for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                                $("#example").append("<tr><td>" + response.d[i].ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID + "</td><td>" + response.d[i].ACCOUNT_ISO_CODE + "</td><td>" + response.d[i].ACCOUNT_DESC + "</td></tr>");
                            debugger;
                        }
                    }

                });
```

MY Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public DbDataModel[] GetData(string network)
    {
        List<DbDataModel> l = new List<DbDataModel>();
        DataTable db = GetDataSource(network);
        foreach (DataRow row in db.Rows)
        {
            DbDataModel model = new DbDataModel();
            model.Account_type_id = row["ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID"].ToString();
            model.Account_iso_code = row["ACCOUNT_ISO_CODE"].ToString();
            model.Account_desc = row["ACCOUNT_DESC"].ToString();
            l.Add(model);
        }
            return l.ToArray();

    }
```

My Model:

```
 public class DbDataModel
{
    public string Account_type_id { get; set; }
    public string Account_iso_code { get; set; }
    public string Account_desc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify where it shows undefined and what exactly is going on

Comment: I have used a dropdown to fetch results from database and the value is passed to the controller through ajax. now the returned result(List<DbDataModel>) is sent to myView through ajax. now i need to display those results in datatable, the query returns 1 row but response.length is 30 and all these rows are shown as undefined in the datatable

Comment: Remove your `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to return JSON

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData(string network)
{
  List<DbDataModel> l = new List<DbDataModel>();
  .....
  return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and in the script

```
...
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got it right.

```
function GetData() {
                pid = $(this).data('id');
                var singleValues = $("#network").val();
                var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                var network = { "network": id };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/GetData',
                    dataType:"json",
                    traditional: true,                            
                    data: jQuery.param( network ),
                    success: function (response) {
                        debugger;
                        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();//get the DataTable
                        oTable.fnClearTable();//clear the DataTable
                            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                //                $("#example").append("<tr><td>" + response[i].Account_type_id + "</td><td>" + response[i].Account_iso_code + "</td><td>" + response[i].Account_desc + "</td></tr>");
                                oTable.fnAddData([
                                    response[i].Account_type_id,
                                    response[i].Account_iso_code,
                                    response[i].Account_desc
                                ]);
                            }

                    }

                });
            };

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetData(string network)
    {
        List<DbDataModel> l = new List<DbDataModel>();
        DataTable db = GetDataSource(network);
        foreach (DataRow row in db.Rows)
        {
            DbDataModel model = new DbDataModel();
            model.Account_type_id = row["ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID"].ToString();
            model.Account_iso_code = row["ACCOUNT_ISO_CODE"].ToString();
            model.Account_desc = row["ACCOUNT_DESC"].ToString();
            l.Add(model);
        }
            return Json(l.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

Doing exactly what I wanted.